# How to overlap div under another div?

Tags: html, css, overlap

I'm trying to set up a web page.
I have this : 
[image: Now]

I did it with this code :

```
    <div style=" width: 100%; text-align: center;">
        <div style="display: inline-block;"><img class="img-responsive" src="/i/g-6-4-9-131_9649_9.jpg" style="float:left;"></div>
        <div style="display: inline-block;"><img class="img-responsive" src="/i/g-6-4-7-131_9647_7.jpg" style="float:left;"></div>
        <div style="display: inline-block;"><img class="img-responsive" src="/i/g-6-4-8-131_9648_8.jpg" style="float:left;"></div>
        <img class="img-responsive" src="/i/g-6-4-6-131_9646_6.jpg" style="width: 100%; height: 5px">
    </div>
```

I want this (the line under the images) : 
[image: result]

Can anyone help me please ? 
Thanks a lot for reading me.

EDIT :

When passing the img in background of the main div, i get this :

```
<div style=" width: 100%; text-align: center; background-image:url(/i/g-6-4-6-131_9646_6.jpg)">
```

[image]

and trying to use z-index this way Iget this :

```
<img class="img-responsive" src="/i/g-6-4-6-131_9646_6.jpg" style="width: 100%; height: 5pxz-index: -1; position: absolute; top: 50%">
```

[image: line disappeared]

Comment: why not set the image as the background of your parent div?

Comment: Thanks for answering, I edited the post to show you

Comment: You should explore the background image solution and read up a bit on background property styles, e.g `background-repeat`, `background-position`, `background-size`, etc (you'll be able to combine a few of these into the `background` shorthand property). You'll need to set a few of them to get the intended behaviour. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background

Comment: It's working, thanks a lot !!!! 
Used  { <div style=" width: 100%; text-align: center; background: repeat-x center url('/i/g-6-4-6-131_9646_6.jpg')"> } for the main div. 
thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

You can "overlap" divs with z-index.
The z-index is you level of the div. You can set it to positive and negative values.

So e.g. z-index: -1 would put the div behind another one and z-index: 2 would put it in front of the other container.

In your case you most likely need to use position: absolute; to place the line directly under the other images, since divs and images are both displayed as blocks and naturally do not overlap.

so, your code should look something like this:

```
  <div style=" width: 100%; text-align: center;">
    <div style="display: inline-block;"><img class="img-responsive" src="/i/g-6-4-9-131_9649_9.jpg" style="float:left;"></div>
    <div style="display: inline-block;"><img class="img-responsive" src="/i/g-6-4-7-131_9647_7.jpg" style="float:left;"></div>
    <div style="display: inline-block;"><img class="img-responsive" src="/i/g-6-4-8-131_9648_8.jpg" style="float:left;"></div>
    <img class="img-responsive" src="/i/g-6-4-6-131_9646_6.jpg" style="width: 100%; height: 5px; z-index: -1; position: absolute; top: 50%">
</div>
```

You have to try which position (for top) suits your needs though.

Comment: Thank you for answering, and for explication that's really nice of you. When I try what you suggest the "line" disappear totally. would it be better to put the <img> inside a div like the other and take the style of the img to the div ?

Comment: There's no need to mess about with z-index if you just move the background image tag before the foreground images.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved doing:

```
 <div style=" width: 100%; text-align: center; background: repeat-x center url('/i/g-6-4-6-131_9646_6.jpg')">        
        <div style="display: inline-block;">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="/i/g-6-4-9-131_9649_9.jpg" style="float:left;">
        </div>
        <div style="display: inline-block;">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="/i/g-6-4-7-131_9647_7.jpg" style="float:left;">
        </div>
        <div style="display: inline-block;">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="/i/g-6-4-8-131_9648_8.jpg" style="float:left;">
        </div>
    </div>
```